# npm installs two versions of a module with different patch versions whilst I'm using caret

Tags: npm, module, version

My projects package.json

```
dependencies: {
    A: "^0.0.2",
    B: "^0.0.1"
}
```

module B package.json

```
dependencies: {
    A: "^0.0.1",
}
```

When I run `nmp install` for my project it installs module A twice. Once in the top level (version 0.0.2) *and one time nested in module B* (version 0.0.1):

```
project/node_modules/A                   <--0.0.2
project/node_modules/B/node_modules/A    <--0.0.1
```

But I'm using *^* in both package.json files. So why, even when I reinstall module B does it not use the top level installation of module A instead of getting a nested version of module A?

After all, `A@^0.0.1` should match `A@0.0.2` right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is as per design. See this answer

[npm install with ^ dependency instead of exact match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47848064/npm-install-with-dependency-instead-of-exact-match)

> That happens because ^0.0.1 is considered to be equivalent to 0.0.1.
>
> When the version of a package starts with 0 it's considered to be in development, and the semantic versioning rules are different. An increase in either of the numbers can be expected to have breaking changes when the version is 0.0.X. You can see the rules here.
>
> **Caret Ranges ^1.2.3 ^0.2.5 ^0.0.4**
>
> Allows changes that do not modify the left-most non-zero digit in the [major, minor, patch] tuple. In other words, this allows patch and minor updates for versions 1.0.0 and above, patch updates for versions 0.X >=0.1.0, and no updates for versions 0.0.X.
>
> You'll probably see the caret when you increment the minor version, but it will also have the special rules that are mentioned over. "Normal" rules start applying when you increment the major version.

You can also look at the below page with more details

https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/semver#caret-ranges-123-025-004

It clearly shows `^0.0.3 := >=0.0.3 <0.0.4`, which means `^0.0.X` is same as `0.0.X`

Comment: yes, I had since found the answer too but forgot to update. I've changed to using tilde '~' for now to match my requirement. Tnx for the well formatted answer!